# How to change the nodeType of XML document from DOCUMENT to ELEMENT

Tags: xmldom

I used XMLDOM to create a document (#1).  I used Load("string").  With another XML document (#2), I want to append the first XMLDOM, but I get an error stating "This operation can not be performed with a Node of type DOCUMENT."  How can I change the node to type ELEMENT (1)?

```
oDOM2 = Createobject(MSXML2.DOMDocument)
<bunch of code and other things go here...>

oDOM1 = Createobject(MSXML2.DOMDocument)
oDOM1.Load("<SomeXML><MoreXML></MoreXML></SomeXML>")
oDOM2.appendChild(oDOM1) -->Error
```

If i use the DOM object to create the object with createElement and addChild, with that fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one way to handle this.  After I have completed my document #1, then I can select a single node (the root) into a new DOM object.  It works for my purpose.

```
oDOM2 = Createobject(MSXML2.DOMDocument)
<bunch of code and other things go here...>

oDOM1 = Createobject(MSXML2.DOMDocument)
oDOM1.Load("<SomeXML><MoreXML></MoreXML></SomeXML>")
oDOMTemp = oDOM1.selectSingleNode("//SomeXML")

oDOM2.appendChild(oDOMTemp)
```

Is there a better way?